# IntelliJ IDEA equivalent of Eclipse "Link with Editor"

Tags: eclipse, editor, intellij-idea

In Eclipse you can check the "Link with Editor" option and whatever source file you are viewing in the current tab will be highlighted and have its package expanded in the Package Explorer view.

Is there something equivalent to this in IntelliJ IDEA 8.1?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Update (2020, eleven years later): see "[Source code navigation / Locate a file in the Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#scroll_to_from_source)"

> In the **`Project`** tool window, right-click the **`Project`** toolbar and, from the context menu, select **`Always Select Opened File`**.
>
> After that IntelliJ IDEA will track the file that is currently opened in the active editor tab and locate it in the **`Project`** tool window automatically.

[image: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/img/idea/2019.3/project_view_context_menu.png]

---

Original answer (2009)

That would be [image: autoscrollFromSource.png] : **Autoscroll from Source**.

Navigate from a file in the Editor that gets the focus, to the corresponding node in the [**Project Tool Window**](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/index.jsp?project-tool-window.html).

[image]

[Fried Hoeben](https://stackoverflow.com/users/225771/fried-hoeben) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746109/intellij-idea-equivalent-of-eclipse-link-with-editor/746287#comment20169192_746287) that

> you get there from the config of the project tool window.
> It is not present in the general IDE settings (at least in version 12)

Comment: Don't forget to get there from the config of the project tool window. It is not present in the general IDE settings (at least in version 12).

Comment: @FriedHoeben interesting. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: This works so that it expands the tree in the project view as files are opened in the editor, however it doesn't close the tree after the files are closed in the editor. Is there anyway to have this behavior?

Comment: @nomel7 I don't know, actually. It could be a good question in its own.

Answer (score 105):

At IntelliJ IDEA 12 (13, 14 and 15 from comments), it is located at the gear icon into the "Project" Tool Window, called as our mate said, **Autoscroll from source**

check the image

[image]

I hope this can helps someone else :)

Comment: Thanks for the details. But how the heck did they decide on a stupid name like this ? It has nothing to do with scrolling

Comment: Helped me. Thank you.

Comment: In Intellij 2019.3 community editor, it is to right-click on the Project view and check the item "Always select opened file"

Comment: @Thomas, your comment should be a new answer, I didn't see until I had found it myself.

Answer (score 3):

In version 2016.3, it's a little icon on the Project Tool Window called Scroll from Source. It's the first icon on the right [see screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxzdD.png)

Answer (score 2):

**Right click** on the **Project Title bar (Project view)**. Then select the Option **"Autoscroll from Resource"**.

Answer (score 1):

In Intellij 2019.3 community editor, it is to right-click on the Project view and check the item "Always select opened file.

Answer (score 1):

Solution to `IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.4 (Community Edition)`

[image]

Click on `Show Options Menu`  and select `Always Select Opened File`
[image]

[image]